# Spring boot + redis, unique sessions

Tags: java, spring, session, heroku, spring-data-redis

I have a Spring Boot application that I have deployed on Heroku. However, I want to create a unique session for each new device that accesses the application, as currently, the data created by one user is visible to all other devices (as it runs on shared memory). I have already added Redis to my code and as a Heroku addon, but the same data is still visible on all devices. Is it possible to create a unique session for each new device without user authorization?

I tried to use Redis with Heroku properties

```
spring.redis.host= .....
spring.redis.port=218500
spring.redis.password=....
```

and also add config from https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/connecting-heroku-redis